# Radiogroup isChecked repeat

Tags: java, android, button, click

В своём приложении я использую radiogroup в которой находится несколько radiobutton.При выборе, radiobutton передаёт имя своего id на активити 2.Со второй активити можно вернутся на первую и выбрать другие варианты radiogroup,вопрос заключается в том,как вернувшись на первое активити с radiogroup выбрать ещё раз выбранный ранее нами вариант,то есть если radiobutton1 уже помечен isCheck(true),но нам надо опять вернутся на вторую активити с данными id по клику на уже отмеченный вариант? 
Небольшой кусок кода:

```
OnCheckedChangeListener rad=newOnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

but = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
int checkedIndex = radioGroup.indexOfChild(but);

SavePreferences("key", checkedIndex);

name =getResources().getResourceEntryName(checkedId);
intent.putExtra("sample",name);

startActivity(intent);
finish();

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, в первой активити, в `onResume()`, у `radioGroup` можно сбрасывать выделение элементов.

```
private RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener mOnCheckedChangeListener = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

        //делаете здесь свои дела и вызываете вторую активити
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    mRadioGroup.clearCheck();
    mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mOnCheckedChangeListener);

}
```

Когда нажмете на второй активити кнопку назад, в первой активити вызовется метод `onResume()` и сбросит выбор в `radioGroup`.

Comment: Это не совсем то,так как при возвращении на первую активити Check должен оставатся,ведь если их будет 20,то пользователю нужно запоминать какой он вариант выбирал,а это не каждому хочется,я решил проблему добавив для какждой radiobutton android:onClick="clickcheck" и в java: public void clickcheck(View view) {

   startActivity(intent);
   finish();

 }.Всё равно пасибо за ответ и потраченное время на мой вопрос,а то я думал все как всегда проигнорили,тут не как за бугром налетают стаей с вариантами ответов